# How to configure ASP.NET Core to have different configurations for two deployed applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I've been learning about ASP.NET environment variables and configurations.

I see that, by default, any settings placed in *appsettings.Development.json* will override the same settings in *appsettings.json* when running in my own local environment. And that *appsettings.Development.json* is not deployed and so does not override any settings when deployed.

My question: Does anyone know a way to use this same mechanism for multiple deployed configurations?

For example, I have a website and a demo version of the website. Both use the same code base but a couple of settings need to be different for the demo site. It would be great if I could create *appsettings.Demo.json* and place any settings in there that need to be overridden just for the demo site.

Currently, I just set an `IsDemoSite` setting in the file. This works but it would be much more elegant if I could have different configuration settings.

I haven't been able to find any documentation about having different configurations when deployed.

Also, one of the differences is that the demo site uses a different database connection string. And so I would need to be able to set which version I'm working on when running migrations, etc.

Comment: Set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to `Demo` and then it will load the demo settings

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: You are on the right track. You can create appsettings.Demo.json file and many configuration files as you want. On your demo site, set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable value to Demo. For more check [this](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/set-appsettings-json-dynamically-dev-and-release-environments-asp-net-core) out

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same thing to do - Your on track with custom appsettings files.

In my case, I wanted a separate development, production, wsl and docker configuration. Solution - given that I was running prod and dev on separate virtual instances, was to use old and true `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

I created required variations of `appsettings` (appsettings.docker etc) and set up aforementioned variable for given files.

In addition as my app starts, it grabs the path to the correct file (part of the name is taken from `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`) and loads it as normal json file to `.ConfigureAppConfiguration` method of `CreateHostBuilder`. It works perfectly for my requirements - should be good for You.

You can find example [here](https://github.com/quain24/ScanApp/blob/990c65d901e245a5889b6bdb75a37ee3ff9695d2/ScanApp/Program.cs#L62).

As for setting up `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` - depends on the host system that You are on:

- For docker

```yaml
# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="docker"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScanApp.dll"]
```

- for Windows:
  Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-by-setting-an-environment-variable) guide - it will guide you through global and in-app settings
- for WSL - in Your `launchSettings.json`:

```json
"WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:5051",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "wsl",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5051;http://localhost:5050"
      },
      "distributionName": "Ubuntu-20.04"
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing key details here. Where and how are you setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable? And how are you switching between configurations? And exactly how does your app "grabs the path to the correct file?" I will check out the example.

Comment: @JonathanWood: One way (arguably the best) is to set it in the `<environmentVariables>` element in web.config, assuming you're deploying to IIS. This sets the environment for the *process* so you can have multiple deployed configurations on the same server.

Comment: The default host builder loads `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{environment}.json` (it's interpolated like that), so it gets the settings for the configured environment.

Comment: When you publish your application, it creates a web.onfig with the `aspNetCore` module configured. You'll need to add the `<environmentVariables>` there, see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-environment-variables).

Comment: @JonathanWood - I've updated my answer, this should help You.

Comment: @madreflection: I would much prefer to handle this within my application rather than custom IIS settings.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-in-code) will help. But, uh, don't knock it 'til you've tried it. It's not exactly a custom IIS setting. It's a module setting.

Comment: I would use the Windows method but I'm still not seeing how I switch between environments, depending on whether I want to deploy the main site or the demo site. If I need to manually edit the files, then I would just continue doing it the way I am.

Comment: Like in my [example](https://github.com/quain24/ScanApp/blob/990c65d901e245a5889b6bdb75a37ee3ff9695d2/ScanApp/Program.cs#L62), you are grabbing value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in app. Using this value, you are loading correct appsettings file on app startup - values from this file will overwrite standard appsettings values. As for demo vs main - to use said way, just setup demo in separate environment - like in docker, new virtual machine, separate server etc. One environment = one version of your site = one `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. When publishing, publish app to both and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not using docker or virtual machines. I don't fully understand your setup. But it doesn't sound right for me.